# My menu animation used to be fade, now it's suddenly slide. How to change it back?

Tags: windows-7

The menu animation on my Win 7 has been fade since forever. I have no idea what happened, but now it's slide, and I can't find any way to change it back. Ideas?

Comment: What menu animation?

Comment: @Stacklearner: when you click an item in the main application menu and the drop-sown menu appears, or when you right-click something and a context menu appears, it may just pop in at once of visual effects are disabled in the Windows performance settings, or it may appear with an animation. The default animation is fade, i. e. it goes from fully transparent to fully opaque. However, my animation suddenly switch to slide which is a sort of unfolding, it's a size animation rather than opacity animation.